# IOS Certificate Wizard not working on latest build under Codename One settings UI in Netbeans 12.3

Tags: codenameone

In Codename One settings UI using Netbeans, click on Build Setings/Device Settings/IOS/Certificate Wizard opens the IOS Certificate Wizard form, however it is asking me to "Please login to your Codename One Account to use this feature. You can login using the menu button on the top right of this form", however I am already logged. I click logout then log back in and see the Logged in Successfully Toastbar at bottom.

Control Center Version is 7.02

ControlCenterIosWizardScreen_09-23-2021.PNG

[image: Control Center IOS Certificate Wizard Screen Shot]

Best regards

Regarding: Did you send a build at some point for some platform?
Yes IOS and Android at least 4 times over the day.

I do not see any "Account Button" in control center.

I am already logged in, [image: Shows I Am Already Logged In]

I logout and then click on the Login Button in the Control Center opens up a browser and shows I am logged in.

What Account Button do you want be to click?[image: Login Success Screen (I did not have to enter password as other devices are logged in)]

I have provided a screen shot on my account in https://cloud.codenameone.com/secure/index.html
[image: Account in Builder]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? Also check the version of settings. It's updated separately from the plugin and should be at 7.02 at the moment.

Comment: And when you press the account button what do you see? Did you send a build at some point for some platform?

Comment: That's odd. Close the settings. Open regedit and search for codename1. Delete everything that you find. Then try logging in again. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, Shai, deleting codename1 in the registry worked. Regards